# How to deploy multiple docker images to an Azure App Service through Azure Pipelines

Tags: docker-compose, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, docker-container

I have a docker compose .yml file that I use to manually install and run multiple docker images on a Linux Azure App Service. My next step is to automate this through Azure Pipelines, which I have been successful in doing for a single image; but can't figure out how to do it for multiple images on the same App Service instance.

This is a client requirement to run multiple images on the same App Service instance. I have some flexibility if there is a much better way, but cost is a factor.

I'm specifically looking for the type of Task to add to my release pipeline and if there are any examples or documentation I can read. So far I haven't found anything that really seems to fit the bill, but I'm not a DevOps engineer, so it's likely I am just not asking the question correctly.

Here is an example of the docker compose yml file I have.

```
version: '3.7'
    services:
      exampleapi:
        image: examplecontainerregistry.azurecr.io/example.api:latest
        container_name: example.api
        volumes:
          - example:/mnt/example
          - common:/mnt/common
      certprojectservice:
        image: examplecontainerregistry.azurecr.io/example.certproject.service:latest
        container_name: example.certproject.service
        volumes:
          - example:/mnt/example
          - common:/mnt/common 
      unityemailservice:
        image: examplecontainerregistry.azurecr.io/example.email.service:latest
        container_name: example.email.service
        volumes:
          - example:/mnt/example
          - common:/mnt/common   
      eventconsumerservice:
        image: examplecontainerregistry.azurecr.io/example.eventconsumers.service:latest
        container_name: example.eventconsumers.service
        volumes:
          - example:/mnt/example
          - common:/mnt/common 
      webhookresponseservice:
        image: examplecontainerregistry.azurecr.io/example.webhookresponse.service:latest
        container_name: example.webhookresponse.service
        volumes:
          - example:/mnt/example
          - common:/mnt/common 
      unitywebhooksservice:
        image: examplecontainerregistry.azurecr.io/example.webhooks.service:latest
        container_name: example.webhooks.service
        volumes:
          - example:/mnt/example
          - common:/mnt/common
```

Answer (score 6):

*Not sure whether the method I used is suitable for you, but you can have a check.*

**1)** To run multi docker images in one Azure app service instance, firstly I need make my Azure App service type is available for **Docker-Compose**:

[image]

*Note: Since my images are stored at ACR, here I make this Azure app service connect to the ACR I used.*

**2)** Upload the `docker-compose.yml` into that **configuration**.

**3)** The third step, which is the very meaningful step is enable **Continuous Deployment**. The significance of this step is once there has new images are pushed to the ACR which connected with the current app service. It will obtain the latest image is automatically from the ACR, and then deploy as the docker-compose file configured.

After enable the **Continuous Deployment**, click on **show url** to get the wehhook URL:

[image]

**4)** Go `ACR`, then select `Webhooks` from left panel. `Add` => Input the `webhook URL` we copied from AppService to `Service URL`. Save it.

[image]

---

Now, every time you push a new version of the image to `ACR`, the Azure App Service will trigger the redeploy of the containers using the most recent image. And I do not need configure pipeline with deploy task in azure devops.

Comment: This is really good information to have; unfortunately in this case it doesn't serve the requirements I have right now to use a pipeline. ( Although it would have served requirements I have had in previous projects, so +1 because very helpful)

Answer (score 2):

So, for anyone interested, the way I was able to solve my exist situation was to make sure that during the build pipeline, I pushed the docker compose file as a Pipeline Artifact. Then in the release pipeline I was able to download that artifact and use it in an Azure CLI task.

The CLI task used the "az webapp config container set" command. Reasonably simple once I figured it out, but a more fit for purpose task would have been nice.

[image: Release Pipeline]

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate a bit more on how you used these tasks?  I am not the greatest at the Azure CLI and I am in the same boat you are currently.